# On trying to save value to an array of custom type. getting "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'id')"

Tags: angular, typescript, model, properties, undefined

I had created a model like this:

```
export class SelectedApplicationFeatures {
id: number;
```

}

and used it in my ts file as:

```
import { SelectedApplicationFeatures } from "src/app/models/selectedApplicationFeatures.model";
selectedApplicationFeatures: SelectedApplicationFeatures[]=[];
```

then if I try to set values in selectedApplicationFeatures in my function like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < _applicationFeatures.length; i++) {

  if (_applicationFeatures[i].featureChecked == true) {

    let j = 0;
    this.selectedApplicationFeatures[j].id = _applicationFeatures[i].id;
//error is happening on the above line. _applicationFeatures[i].id is returning proper integer value.
    j++;
  }
}
```

I am getting an error:
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')".

//_applicationFeatures:

[application features array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xorWr.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpbs0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in the variable `selectedApplicationFeatures: SelectedApplicationFeatures[];`. You should initialize it first as:

```js
selectedApplicationFeatures: SelectedApplicationFeatures[] = [];
```

And then, instead of assigning an unknown number of elements to `selectedApplicationFeatures` maybe appending would be better. Take a look at the fix below:

```
for (let i = 0; i < _applicationFeatures.length; i++) {
  if (_applicationFeatures[i].featureChecked == true) {
    this.selectedApplicationFeatures.push({id: _applicationFeatures[i].id};
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but actually I want selectedApplicationFeatures like this:
[
0:{id:1},
1:{id:4},
2:{id: 5}
]
the error is happening on this line:

 this.selectedApplicationFeatures[j].id = _applicationFeatures[i].id;

Comment: Can you update the question with the right initialization of `selectedApplicationFeatures`. Also, is it on a class? If not, you don't need to use `this` in `this.selectedApplicationFeatures[j].id`

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please take a look